# Proof involving nilpotent linear operator of order 3.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space, and let $T:V\rightarrow V$ be a nilpotent linear operator of order $3$ (a linear operator is "nilpotent of order $k$" if $k$ is the minimum integer for which $T^k(v)=0$ for all $v\in V$).
I want to prove that $Ker(T)\subset Im(T)$, specifically, I want to show that $Ker(T)$ is included in $Im(T)$ but $Ker(T)\neq Im(T)$.

I was able to show why $Ker(T)\neq Im(T)$, this is because: suppose that there exists $v\in Im(T)$ s.t. $v\in Ker(T)$.
So $v\in Im(T)\Rightarrow \exists w\in V$ s.t. $T(w)=v$.
Applying $T^2$ to both sides, we get: $T^3(w)=T^2(v)\Rightarrow T^2(v)=0\Rightarrow T(v)\in Ker(T)$ $\forall v\in V$.
Contradiction. Since $T$ is nilpotent of order 3.

I couldn't figure out the inclusion. Can someone please guide me?

EDIT**

Now that I think about it, my proof for $Ker(T)\neq Im(T)$ is not correct...
That last implication is wrong: $T^2(v)=0\Rightarrow T(v)\in Ker(T)$ $\forall v\in V$ because this should be $\forall v\in Im(T)$, not $\forall v\in V$, so I can't conclude that $T$ is nilpotent of order 2, hence there is no contradiction... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what I was missing.
Here's the proof, in case anyone will be interested. I Generalized it to a nilpotent transformation $T$ of order $n\geq 3$:

*Inclusion part*:
Since $T$ is nilpotent of order $n$, then there exist $v\in V$ for which $T^{n-1}(v)\neq 0$.
Furthermore, the set $B=\{v,T(v),T^2(v),...,T^{n-1}(v)\}$ is linearly independent (that's not too hard to show), and therefore forms a basis for $V$.

Now, let $w\in KerT$, so $T(w)=0\Rightarrow T(a_1v+a_2T(v)+a_3T^2(v)+...+a_nT^{n-1}(v))=0$
$\Rightarrow a_1T(v)+a_3T(v)+a_4T^2(v)+...+a_nT^n(v)=0$
$\Rightarrow a_1T(v)+a_3T(v)+a_4T^2(v)+...+a_{n-1}T^{n-1}(v)=0$
$\Rightarrow a_i=0\hspace{8pt} \forall 1\leq i\leq n-1$

So $w=a_nT^{n-1}(v)\Rightarrow w=T(a_nT^{n-2}(v)) \Rightarrow w\in ImT$.

*Inequality part*:
Take that $v$ again, so $T^{n-1}(v)\neq 0$.
Since $T^{n-1}(v)\neq 0$ then $ T^{n-2}(v)\notin KerT$, but clearly $T^{n-2}(v)=T(T^{n-3}(v))\in ImT$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x \in Ker(T)$ and suppose it is not in $Im(T)$. So for all $u \in V: T(u) \neq x$. So
$$ 0 = T^3(u) \neq T^2(x) = 0$$
What should lead to a contradiction.

Comment: wait, why is $T(u)\neq x\Rightarrow T^3(u)\neq T^2(x)$?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, I currently think that this does not work always (at least I don't see it). I will try to improve this but yet I did not find a way to repair the contradiction.

Comment: OK, thanks for the help. Add a comment here if you'll make any progress and I'll do the same. I'll mark it as unanswered to give more people a chance to answer.